# looking for a call or thread id to use for logging

Tags: logging, go

I am reworking the logging of our little web application written in golang. Due to external requirements logging has been isolated in one place so we can potentially switch in a **logging server** later on. (Not my idea - I promise....) Nevertheless we are now able to log the common things like date/time, line number, user and the message mostly using parts of the standard library and a user/session struct we are passing around.

But - and here comes the question - in lower level methods it is a waste to pass in the session just to get to the user name for the sake of logging. So I would like to find something else to use to find one specific request in the log files. I am sure there are something obvious I haven't thought of.

Ideas so far:

- Java logging frameworks can print out the thread id and that would be good enough in this case also. Just that it is called something else in golang?
- make the user/session struct thing accesible globally somehow. (Still need to pass the session id around unless there are a thread to use as lookup key. Back to idea number 1.)
- give up and pass the user/session struct around anyway.
- don't log errors on the lowest level but only when the user/session struct is available. The line number won't be that good though.

We are using parts of gorilla for web things and apart from that mostly the standard library.

Suggestions and ideas about this?

Comment: You have no real choice : you must somewhat pass a reference to your user (explicitly or via a closure), there's no such thing as a goroutine id.

Comment: Have you considered using something like expvar? (http://golang.org/pkg/expvar/) "Package expvar provides a standardized interface to public variables, such as operation counters in servers. It exposes these variables via HTTP at /debug/vars in JSON format." Could help for globally accessible stats.

Comment: nope - interesting package. not sure how it helps me though - I will still need something to address the thing with. some kind of key? right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because of the high potential for abuse, there is no way to access an identifier for the current goroutine in Go. This may seem draconian, but this actually preserves an important property of the Go package ecosystem: *it does not matter if you start a new goroutine to do something*.

That is, for any method of function F:

```
F()
```

is almost exactly equivalent to:

```
done := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
   defer close(done)
   F()
}
<-done
```

(The "almost" comes from the fact that if F panics, the panic
will not be caught by the original goroutine).

This applies to logging too - if you were using the current goroutine
to infer the current user, any code that started a new goroutine
as above would break that assumption, and your logging
would not contain the expected information.

You'll need to pass around some kind of context.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes lots of sense. I suspect I will pass the context around but not all the way down. I think we will add extra logging if problems detected only makes sense with the context. In this way the code will stay reasonably clean.

Comment: IMHO "high potential for abuse" is kinda fishy. It would introduce a need to enumerate Go routines in the first place.

Comment: @rog: I quoted parts of this answer in [this blog post about logging](http://highlevelbits.com/2013/10/single_point_logging.html).

Comment: Isn't it for the golang snippet to be equivalent of _call_ of function `F`, it should be
`go func() { ...}()`? Note `()` at the end. (≖_≖ )

Comment: there are 100% legitimate reasons to need to know the go thread when looking through log lines because intermingled log lines can confuse the logic. Most people get around this with some sort of unique id on the struct they're using in their threads.

Unless the language provides complete thread safety, it matters if something is running in a thread or not, and no ideological position will change that.